# Using Where with Powershell + CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read some device names from a .csv and compare them with AzureAD. The .csv in question only has one column with device names. Building the code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/manage-stale-devices

I'm modifying their code here:

```html
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where {$_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp -le $dt} | select-object -Property AccountEnabled, DeviceId, DeviceOSType, DeviceOSVersion, DisplayName, DeviceTrustType, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp | export-csv devicelist-olderthan-90days-summary.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

```html
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$Names = @()
Import-Csv -Path C:\test123\Computers.csv | ForEach-Object {$Names += $_.Name}

Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where {($_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp -le $dt) -and ($_.DisplayName -eq $Names)} | select-object -Property DisplayName, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp | export-csv oldcomputers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However, the csv that's created is blank. Is there some issue with how I'm searching the local .csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if an element exist in an array you have several options (`-in`, `-contains`, `.contains(..)`, etc). See [containment_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#containment-operators) for detailed info.

Try with something like this:

```
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$names = (Import-Csv -Path C:\test123\Computers.csv).Name

Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where-Object {

    $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp -le $dt -and
    $_.DisplayName -in $Names
    # => OR $Names -contains $_.DisplayName
    # => OR $Names.contains($_.DisplayName) => This one is case sensitive

} | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp |
Export-Csv C:\path\to\oldcomputers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

#### Edit

To explain what could possible be happening, as in my comment, `-in` and `-contains` are looking for an exact match on the `$names` array.

**Example**

```
'two' -in 'one','two','three' # => True
'twooo' -in 'one','two','three' # => False
```

```
'one','two','three' -contains 'two' # => True
'one','two','three' -contains 'tttwo' # => False
```

As a workaround, you could try using `-match` which would be looking for a partial match and also allows the use of [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1):

```
'two' -match 'one|two|three' # => True
'tttwo' -match 'one|two|three' # => True
'twooo' -match 'one|two|three' # => True
```

---

Try with this instead:

```
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

# NOTE: (...).Name => Where .Name is the header or column name, if the
# header is named differently change it here too  
$names = (Import-Csv -Path C:\test123\Computers.csv).Name -join '|'

Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where-Object {

    $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp -le $dt -and
    $_.DisplayName -match $names

} | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, ApproximateLastLogonTimestamp |
Export-Csv C:\path\to\oldcomputers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I really appreciate you reaching out Santiago, unfortunately the exported .csv returns blank with all cases. However, the reverse, -notcontains/-notin works. But not in the conventional sense, it simply returns the full list of devices, as if "$_.DisplayName -notin $Names" was commented out. I think it's returning as "true", so it doesn't print the comparison. Any ideas?

Comment: @The28thCode can you share a few examples of how a `DisplayName` from `Get-AzureADDevice` looks and a few examples of what your CSV contains? Its ok if you obfuscate them, I need to have a perspective of what we are comparing here because `-in` and `-contains` are looking for an exact match.

Comment: Sure, a cell within the .csv would look like so: **CODE-12345, CODE-22345, CODE-32345**. While objects pulled from `DisplayName` would have similar entries to the CSV, but also contain obscure prefixes, like **L-12345, BOBBY-12345, or Santiago_OnePlus_08/11/2021_2:21 PM**.

Comment: @The28thCode see my last edit, hope it helps :)